# Scalac: Assertion failed while run Scalatest in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, jetbrains-ide

I am running a ScalaTest Suite inside Intellij IDEA, during the make phase before scala test, I run into this problem:

```
Error:scalac: Error: assertion failed: List(object package$DebugNode, object package$DebugNode)
      java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(object package$DebugNode, object package$DebugNode)
       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.suchThat(Symbols.scala:1678)
       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol.companionModule0(Symbols.scala:2988)
       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol.companionModule(Symbols.scala:2991)
       at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JPlainBuilder.genClass(GenASM.scala:1371)
       at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:120)
       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1583)
       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1557)
       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1553)
       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1662)
       at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)
       at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)
       at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:28)
       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:25)
       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:64)
       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:22)
       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Is it a jetbrains error due to incremental compilation? or Its related to the Test Suite I was running? Nothing information in the stack trace are related to the TestSuite/project I was test on.

Comment: Certainly looks like a compiler error. Does a clean build fix it? Compilation from sbt?

Comment: @ggovan I clean and rebuild the project in terminal using sbt clean/assembly successfully, but went into this error again when I try to run ScalaTest suite inside the project.

Answer (score 4):

I think it was an error due to Interllij IDEA incremental compilation. I got the same error when I built Spark for the first time.

I went to Preferences > Scala, set Incrmental compilation by SBT incremental compiler, Name Hasing: Default, Compilation order: Mixed. Recompiled the code, everything was OK then.

Comment: I've had exactly the same experience in IDEA (the same changes that you did fixed it for me also), while in Eclipse it went through without errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "Name Hashing", I cannot find this in IDEA14.1.5. Do you mean Make again in IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I met such issue before, because I built the spark in command and then imported into IDEA, rebuild will see the two errors, solve it is very easy, just run "mvn clean" under root folder of spark in command line, then Make again in IDEA, the errors gone.

details of TestSQLContext.scala assertion failed ref to: http://www.dataguru.cn/thread-537920-1-1.html

and more details about build spark 1.4.1 on Linux ref to: http://www.dataguru.cn/thread-539343-1-1.html

fredericyuan